# Getting the error "Access to requested resource is denied" for Amazon SP-API would like help verifying credentials

Tags: amazon-product-api, amazon-selling-partner-api

Trying to access the Amazon SP-API via the ruby gem amz_sp_api. The gem works by getting an `access_token` from the `refresh_token` on every API request, so I just need a `refresh_token`

And no matter what I do I get:

`Access to requested resource is denied`

I am using this list of credentials to access the api:

```
refresh_token
client_id
client_secret
aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key
region
```

I've read all the posts on the interwebs, and no luck. So I thought I'd paste in screen grabs of all the places where I'm getting these credentials and hoping someone can verify or discredit my mess. Here goes:

**refresh_token**
I am getting the `refresh_token` via this URL that I constructed with `application_id`

```
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/apps/authorize/consent?application_id=amzn1.sp.solution.1233da7c-a329-49d7-9b29-a6e55de823e0&state=1237&version=beta
```

The application id was found here:
[image: Amazon App Id]

Next the **client_id** and **client_secret**
[image: Amazon Client Id and Client Secret]

Then finally the **aws_access_key_id** and **aws_secret_access_key** that I got when creating my IAM user:
[image: AWS ids]

And yes I assumed the role for the AWS user and that role id looks like this:

```
arn:aws:iam::536EDITED:role/SellerAPIRole
```

Any idea where I went astray?

Comment: I am getting same error. How you resolved?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue when using the Python sp-api. After hours of searching, I found what was missing. In my case it was the `marketplace` parameter – and that resolved my issue.

```
Orders(credentials=credentials,marketplace=Marketplaces.IN).get_orders(CreatedAfter=(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=20)).isoformat())
```

Comment: this answer helped me. thank you! I wish they place all of their required fields at the top of the list.